# what differences between verbal noun and gerund?

Tags: grammar, nouns, gerunds

some verbs can be used as nouns,so what differences between verbal noun and gerund?
for example:
1.Winning is not everything. (does "win" work?)
2.Please return it after use.(does "using" work?)
3.Walking is a good form of exercise for both young and old. (does "walk" work?)

please give me the reasons,or if both work,any different meanings? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Winning is not everything. (does "win" work?)

Yes, but as a verb it would need to be in the *to-infinitive form*: "*To win is not everything*". It sounds very formal, but sayings like this often are - for example "*to know is to understand*". As a noun it would be "**a** win is not everything".

> 2. Please return it after use. (does "using" work?)

"Using" could work, but only as a verb. As this is an instruction or command - the kind you might see on a sign or notice - the strict rules of grammar do not always apply. As a noun, "use" is countable, so if you wanted it to be grammatical rather than instructional you might want to say "after *each* use".

> 3. Walking is a good form of exercise for both young and old. (does "walk" work?)

"Walk" as a verb doesn't sound right. It would have to be "*To walk* is good exercise", which may be grammatically correct as in your first question, but it isn't at all idiomatic, I can't imagine anyone saying it. As a noun, it would be "**a** walk is a good form of excercise.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply.I know "To win" is right,but I still want to know why 'win' cannot be subject alone, 'win' is a noun itself as well as verb.

Comment: "To win" *is* a verb. If you wanted to use it as a noun you would have to say "**A** win".

Comment: got it! thank you very much!